# What is the %<-% operator in R?

Tags: r, operators

I came across a new piped R operator `%<-%` on this blog: https://blogs.rstudio.com/ai/posts/2019-09-30-bert-r/ in the `tokenize_fun()` function.

What is this operator called? What does it do?

I could not find any information about it on google. I am aware of other pipe operators like `%>%`, `%T>%`, `%$%`

Comment: It takes what's on the left and assigns it to the right. I am not sure what it's name is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a multiple assignment operator from `zeallot`

> %<-% and %->% invisibly returnvalue.

> These operators are used primarily for their assignment side-effect.
> %<-% and %->% assign into the environment in which they are evaluated.

i.e. it creates multiple objects from a single line of code

```
> library(zeallot)
> c(x, y, z) %<-% c(1, 3, 5)
> x
[1] 1
> y
[1] 3
> z
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 2):

If one looks at the code in the linked post, it is evident what this operator does. Let's take a look at the first line in the tokenize_fun:

```
tokenize_fun = function(dataset) {
  c(indices, target, segments) %<-% list(list(),list(),list())
```

That line essentially creates three empty lists in a main list to hold indices, target, and segments. These are later populated via `append`.

Edit: There's an answer on the specific name of the function below. I'll leave this answer here in case it may provide some additional context.

In general, one can define an `infix` operator in the %. %` form. In this case, the authors perhaps wanted to "mimic" something like python's multiple assignment via a one-liner.

Comment: Interesting. I tried the following code: `c(indices, target, segments) %<-% c(list(),list(),list())` and it throws an error. But it works with `c(indices, target, segments) %<-% list(list(),list(),list())`.

Comment: I am on mobile, I'd have to check on PC. Perhaps because you can't store lists inside vectors? (I've never tried it)

Comment: It seems like a design thing: See https://github.com/r-lib/zeallot/issues/38 The original author of the package seems to prefer lists to vectors.

Comment: `c(list(), list(), ...)` simplifies to `list()`, similar to `c(list(), NULL, NULL, ...)`

Comment: @rawr: Yes. `c(a,b)%<-%c(list(2),list(3))` works just fine. R and it's quirks.

Comment: @tushaR:  That last one isn't a quirk, it's a lucky coincidence.  `c(list(2),list(3))` is the same as `list(2,3)`.  This wouldn't work:  `c(list(1:2),list(1:3))` because that's the same as `list(1L,2L,1L,2L,3L)`.  R has quirks, but this is a case of it behaving consistently.

Comment: `c(list(1:2),list(1:3))` and `list(1L,2L,1L,2L,3L)` aren't the same